# How should I re-negotiate the compensation for internship?

Tags: internship, negotiation, india, compensation

I am a 2nd year MBA student with about 2 years of work experience. Recently I had to join this company for a 4-month internship because it is part of the syllabus of the MBA program.

Anyway I am doing the "internship" but I am finding nothing new to learn and I am being assigned the same job what I used to do previously but getting 1/5th of the compensation. I feel like I should re-negotiate because it's like I am doing a job in the name of internship but I am not sure how this will turn out. On top of that I have to spend daily for about 4 hours in transit.

Comment: Your compensation is being able to graduate from your MBA program.

Answer (score 10):

You could threaten to quit.    But then you wouldn't get class credit.   The company knows this, so there isn't likely anything you can do.

Honestly?    It's how the game is played.   Be happy to get ANY pay for an internship--many internships are done for no pay.   Just deal with it and get your class credit, then move on.   If you really are doing a good job, the company might offer you the job at 5x the pay you're getting now.

Answer (score 3):

> *Recently I had to join this company for 4 month internship*

So, you're saying, you were "instructed" to join **this** company? Most likely not, you chose to. During the time of the appointment, they would have mentioned about the compensation structure - why did not you think of the payout then? Same goes about the commute.

Reality is: It's a 4-month internship and usually the companies do not "expect" the interns to "deliver" much value to the organization, they are there to **learn**. So, trying to compare the compensation structure with that of a full-time employee (which you were before) is not correct.

> *I feel like I should re-negotiate because it's like I am doing job in the name of internship but I am not sure how this will turn out.*

On what grounds? That they are making you learn? They are assigning the work for you to learn, it's not really their problem whether you are already experienced or not. You should have clarified those points during the internship application and interview - now it's very less likely that they are going to be willing to open a (re)negotiation, at all.

Given that you accepted the offer and now, by seeing the work pattern is known to you, you are feeling you are entitled to get more. Well, you will get more, once you complete the internship , get a degree and find a job.

Till then, you need to hang on.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Irony? I was trying to put emphasis...but I'll correct if that clears any confusion. Thanks

Comment: Quotes should never be used for emphasis, as they are often used to show irony. (Which gives the opposite effect). Example: ' The people were "free" ' implies that the people, while supposedly meant to be free, were not. (For the record, your English is way better than my Bengali; I'm just trying to be helpful)

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Sure, and I thank you for trying to correct me in first place. You don't have to tell me, I know you're trying to help. :) And I have now used **bold** for emphasis, so it should be okay, right?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Wait, how do you know about Bengali? Where did I give up the fact? :D

Comment: Bold is perfect. As for learning about your knowledge of Bengali: I have "sophisticated" means of figuring this out. (I looked at your profile).

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Ah, I see, indeed. The other day, I spoke to Nofel in Hindi in chat....so I was wondering how do you know about Bengali because I did not mention that in Chat. :)